# extraer datos iguales de columnas

Tags: r

Hola Estoy tratando de buscar los nombres que son iguales entre las dos columnas como el siguiente ejemplo.

```
       [,1]      [,2]     
 [1,] "jara"   "moreno" 
 [2,] "moreno"  "lopez"  
 [3,] "diaz"    "Swanson"
 [4,] "powell"  "jara"   
 [5,] "Mckinze" "jenner" 
 [6,] "jenner"  "londra" 
 [7,] "londra"  "kennedy"
```

y necesito al final tener dentro de una matriz los nombres que son iguales como la siguiente matriz:

```
      [,1]    
[1,] "moreno"
[2,] "jara"  
[3,] "jenner"
[4,] "londra"
```

Existe alguna función para realizar esto? además son 10 columnas con mas o menos 50 mil datos cada una.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Que ocurre si el nombre se repite en una misma columna? ¿debe considerarse repetido?

Comment: no se repite, eso es seguro

Comment: Perfecto, con la primera solución de mi respuesta ya te alcanzaría entonces. Saludos

Comment: No se si puedas responder esto, si quisiera extraer los nombres de la columna a que no están en la b se puede?

Comment: A ver.. los nombres en la columna 1 que no estén en la columna 2, lo más simple: `dat[!dat[,1] %in% dat[,2], 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar preparemos tus datos en un ejemplo reproducible:

```
dat <- read.table(text='N1, N2
                        "jara",   "moreno" 
                        "moreno",  "lopez"  
                        "diaz",    "Swanson"
                        "powell",  "jara"   
                        "Mckinze", "jenner" 
                        "jenner",  "londra" 
                        "londra",  "kennedy"', 
                  header=T, sep=',', stringsAsFactors = F, quote = '"', strip.white = T)
```

Esto nos deja un `data.frame` pero para ser más justos, tus datos parecen ser una matriz sin nombre de columnas, por lo que haremos esto:

```
dat <- as.matrix(dat)
colnames(dat) <- NULL
dat

     [,1]      [,2]     
[1,] "jara"    "moreno" 
[2,] "moreno"  "lopez"  
[3,] "diaz"    "Swanson"
[4,] "powell"  "jara"   
[5,] "Mckinze" "jenner" 
[6,] "jenner"  "londra" 
[7,] "londra"  "kennedy"
```

Ahora si, tenemos los datos tal como has planteado, vayamos a la solución. Una forma de obtener los valores repetidos de una columna en otra, podría ser: `dat[dat[,1] %in% dat[,2], 1]`, eso nos da los valores de la columna 1 que son idénticos a los de la columna 2. Sin embargo es complicado hacerlo así, por que además deberías verificar al revés también,  los de la columna 2 que son iguales a los de la 1. Y así con las 10 variables/columnas que mencionas.

Pero por suerte tenemos una función muy útil para contar frecuencias que es [`table()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/table.html), de manera que podríamos hacer esto:

```
tbl <- table(dat)
names(tbl[tbl > 1])
[1] "jara"   "jenner" "londra" "moreno"
```

Con `table(dat)` obtenemos una tabla de frecuencias de todas los variables y observaciones de tu matriz, eventualmente deberías "recortarla" a aquellas columnas que te interesen. El resultado es algo así:

```
   diaz    jara  jenner kennedy  londra   lopez Mckinze  moreno  powell Swanson 
      1       2       2       1       2       1       1       2       1       1
```

Bastante claro, ahora, solo restaría obtener los nombres que tengan más de una ocurrencia y eso lo hacemos con `names(tbl[tbl > 1])`.

**Aclaración Importante**: esta solución contará como repetido dentro de la misma columna también. Si no quieres obtener un nombre que solo se ha repetido en una única columna, hay un pequeño truco para hacerle a esta solución:

```
tbl <- table(apply(dat, 2, function(x) {ifelse(duplicated(x), NA, x)}))
names(tbl[tbl > 1])
```

Básicamente lo que estamos haciendo con `apply(dat, 2, function(x) {ifelse(duplicated(x), NA, x)})` es quitar dentro de cada columna, los valores que se repiten remplazándolos por `NA` y luego contar efectivamente las ocurrencias.

Answer (score 2):

Por lo que se ve tus datos están en una matriz. Para este tipo de operación creo que sería mucho más simple trabajar con un data.frame, sobre todo porque es más fácil "llamar" a las columnas.

## Solución para el ejemplo

```
library(tidyverse)   #Para tribble y otras funciones: 

nombres <- tribble(
     ~a,     ~b,
   "jara"   ,"moreno" ,
   "moreno" , "lopez"  ,
   "diaz"   , "Swanson",
   "powell" , "jara"   ,
   "Mckinze", "jenner" ,bar
   "jenner" , "londra" ,
   "londra" , "kennedy")

nombres$a[nombres$a %in% nombres$b]
```

Que se leería como "todas las filas de `nombres$a` cuando `nombres$a` pertenece a `nombres$b` y regresa el siguiente vector:

```
[1] "jara"   "moreno" "jenner" "londra"
```

Podrías usar `as.matrix()` para pasarlo a matriz.

## Usando `dplyr::filter()`

```
nombres %>% 
  filter(a %in% b)
```

Regresa un data.frame con todas las filas que tienen match.

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
a      b      
<chr>  <chr>  
1 jara   moreno 
2 moreno lopez  
3 jenner londra 
4 londra kennedy
```

Para hacer la comparación con más de dos columnas sería necesario que aclares un poco qué sería un match en ese caso ¿Cuando hay coincidencia en al menos dos columnas cualquiera? ¿Cuando es entre `a` y cualquier otra que no sea `a`? ¿Qué habría que hacer si hay match en más de dos columnas? Te sugiero editar la pregunta con un ejemplo con más de dos columnas y presentar el resultado esperado. El ejemplo mínimo que incluyes está bien formulado, sin embargo el caso real que mencionas al final es diferente.

Comment: Una pregunta, la función de la librería Dplyr necesita alguna clase en especial?, lo que pasa es que sale este mensaje:
  Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
    no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class 
  "logical"

Comment: `dplyr::` y sus funciones sólo aceptan data.frames como input.  `a` y `b` deberían ser de la misma clase (`character` o `factor`) y la operación que se hace con `%in%` debe regresar un vector lógico (puedes probarlo fuera del `filter` para ver si el problema ese). `filter()` tiene conflictos con otras funciones de nombre igual, prueba `dplyr::filter() ` para asegurarte que estás llamando a la función correcta.